# Filter options in a select using a second select value with Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have several couple of selects

I would like to only display to the user options from this "sub" select that have the same class as the value of the second select :

```
<select name="businesssubdomain" id="businesssubdomain">

<option class = "1" value="1">SD_APLIB</option>
<option class = "1" value="2">SD_FICOCO</option>
<option class = "1" value="3">SD_FICOFRAU</option>
<option class = "1" value="4">SD_FICOAM</option>
<option class = "1" value="5">SD_FICOPMR</option>
<option class = "1" value="6">SD_FICOPM</option>
<option class = "1" value="7">SD_FICORCT</option>
<option class = "2" value="8">SD_EDMCCLOE</option>
<option class = "2" value="9">SD_EDMCESO</option>
<option class = "3" value="10">SD_GEDDIAD</option>
<option class = "3" value="11">SD_GEDSCAN</option>
<option class = "3" value="12">SD_GEDSCOR</option>
...

<select name="businessdomain" id="businessdomain">

<option value="1">D_FICO</option>
<option value="2">D_EDMC</option>
<option value="3">D_GED</option>
...
```

For exemple, if I select D_EDMC (value 2) in the second select I should only display SD_EDMCCLOE and SD_EDMCESO (class 2) in the first select.

I have very little skills in Javascript and I would like to do it using Dojo. How can I do ?

Comment: I there a reason why you want to do this without jQuery? This stuff is really one of the strengths of jQuery. Is another JavaScript library an option?

Comment: Because it's not used anywhere else in the project. But dojo is.

Comment: Well, then you should ask how to do it with dojo and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: This would be the jQuery solution: http://codepen.io/timbuethe/pen/FsthL. Sorry, don't know much about dojo though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Dojo you could do something like this:

```js
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-dom", "dojo/NodeList-traverse", "dojo/domReady!"],   function(query) {
    var changeSubdomains = function(value) {
        query("#businesssubdomain option").style("display", "none");
        query("#businesssubdomain option." + value).style("display", "block").at(0).attr("selected", "selected");
    };

    query("#businessdomain").on("change", function(evt) {
        changeSubdomains(evt.target.value);
    });
});
```

What happens here is that we connect an event handler to the `change` event of the `#businessdomain` select. We then hide all options and only show these that have the same classname as the value of the selected option (as requested).

An example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4JfJW/).

Comment: Thanks, it works!
Just a question, with "at(0).attr("selected", "selected")" you select the first option of the resulting select. But it only works when I chose a class greater than the last selected class.
If i chose a lesser class the selected option doesn't change